# Matching Word with regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have the following text file:

```
...
"somewords MYWORD";123123123123
"someother MYWORDOTHER";456456456456
"somedifferent MYWORDDIFFERENT";789789789
...
```

I need to match the word MYWORD, MYWORDOTHER, MYWORDDIFFERENT and then substitute the space before this word with ";".
Someone can figure out a regex?

I have done something like that:

```
 +[^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ]";
```

but this works only with a specific word length. I need to modify to get any word of any length.

Any help?

Comment: So...every line has only one space?

Comment: no more space like that:

    `...
    "rabba somewords MYWORD";123123123123
    "fafa someother MYWORDOTHER";456456456456
    "juju somedifferent MYWORDDIFFERENT";789789789
    ...`

sorry i can't format better that this... :-(

Answer (score 0):

why don't you `str_replace()` ?

```
$string = '"somewords MYWORD";123123123123
"someother MYWORDOTHER";456456456456
"somedifferent MYWORDDIFFERENT";789789789';

$replace = str_replace(' MYWORD', ';MYWORD', $string);
echo $replace;
```

[Codepad Example](http://codepad.org/FJoEu8AT)

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but should work to replace the space before the last word in the quotes...

```
preg_replace('/(".+) (\w+";\d+)/',"$1;$2", $your_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/\s(\w+);\d/', ';$1', $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
$result = preg_replace('/([ ])(\w+)";/im', ';$2";', $subject);
```

in:

```
"somewords MYWORD";123123123123 
"someother MYWORDOTHER";456456456456 
"somedifferent MYWORDDIFFERENT";789789789
```

out:

```
"somewords;MYWORD";123123123123
"someother;MYWORDOTHER";456456456456
"somedifferent;MYWORDDIFFERENT";789789789
```

Comment: ...and this...second winner :-)

Comment: sorry but i can't vote because i have less that 15 of reputation...how can do?

Comment: This is your question so I think you can mark solution as "accepted". But I am not sure. Never mind.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
preg_replace('#"(\w+)\s+(\w+)"#',"$1;$2",$text);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while($line=fgets($file))
{
    $str=preg_replace("/ (\w)/i",";$1",$line);//use this line if you want to replace every space
    $str=preg_replace("/ (\w+)\";(\d)/i",";$1\";$2",$line);//use this line if you only want to replace the last space
    echo $str;//or wherever you want to output
}
```

**Edit**:

Alright, I made a typo in the original answer.

Now corrected with a codepad:http://codepad.org/leQHTuFR

Comment: $str=preg_replace("/ (\w+);\"(\d)/i",";$1;\"$2",$line);//use this line if you only want to replace the last space

this can be the better of this topic.
But unluck not substitute the last space of the first comma that i need...it's possibile to change in order to get this done?

Comment: @lbar Oops, sorry, I made a typo in the regular expression. Now fixed with a codepad example.

Comment: we have two winnere here...this one and below... :-)

Comment: sorry but i can't vote because i have less that 15 of reputation...how can do?

Comment: @lbar Just did a quick check at [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) and seems there's nothing really you can do right now...just accept either one answer.